# Is there any way to add an event listener in a method in a component A, and have the target in a separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I want to add an event listener to the component `Table` so that every time I save a form in the component `Form` by the method `saveForm()` I call a method called `showData()` in the component `Table`.

Form Component

```
let persons = [];

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null)
    persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));


saveForm(myForm) {
        persons.push(myForm);
        localStorage.setItem("personsForms", JSON.stringify(persons));

    }
```

Table Component

```
let persons;

let localStoragePersons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
persons = localStoragePersons !== null ? localStoragePersons : [];


    showData() {
        let table = document.getElementById('editableTable');
        let x = table.rows.length;
        while (--x) {
            table.deleteRow(x);
        }
        let i = 0;

        ...........
    }
```

Comment: What is the relation between `Table` and `Form`? Parent, Child, siblings? Who renders who?

Comment: Table Component and Form Component are both children of the App Component

Comment: Ok, they're siblings. Then that method should be declared inside the parent, component, which is `App`. So it can pass down as `props`. If you're not happy with that, you might need to change your component hierarchy. Would it make any sense  for `Form` to be a child of `Table`?

Comment: Unfortunately i am restricted not to do both ways.

Comment: Can `showData` be declared inside parent? If not, you might be able to get around it, but it would be an anti-pattern. This is usually because you're not building your component hierarchy in the best way.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't recommend doing the anti-pattern, though. See how ugly and unreadable it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Table component is the parent component of Form component.

Pass the method as a prop to Form Component and call it accessing to the props (this.props.parentMethod())

Comment: Table Component and Form Component are both children of the App Component

Comment: I think you want refresh the table with the new data. So I would create a flag In App Component State with a method to toggle it. Pass this method to the Form Component call it on finish saveForm(). Pass flag to Table component and use it at render to force refresh

Comment: Is not the best practice, but you cant do anything more with this structure

Answer (score 0):

From [**React DOCS**](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html):

> **Remember:** React is all about **one-way data flow down the component hierarchy.** It may not be immediately clear which component should own what state. This is often the most challenging part for newcomers to understand, so follow these steps to figure it out:

React's one-way data flow is meant to be **top-down**, parent-child. The way you're suggesting would be sibling-to-sibling, which would be **side-to-side** instead of **top-down**. This is an anti-pattern.

You can set up your component hierarchy like this:

See it that works for you.

```js
function App() {
  
  function doSomethingApp(formValue) {
    console.log('Do something from App!');
    console.log('Form value is: ' + formValue);
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table/>
      <Form
        doSomethingApp={doSomethingApp}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Table(props) {
  
  function doSomethingTable(formValue) {
    console.log('Do something from Table!');
    console.log('Form value is: ' + formValue);
  }
  
  return(
    <div>I am Table</div>
  );
}

function Form(props) {
  const [value,setValue] = React.useState('');
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Form</div>
      <input type='text' value={value} onChange={()=>setValue(event.target.value)}/>
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>props.doSomethingApp(value)}>Do something from App</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**SNIPPET: ATTENTION, THIS IS AN ANTI-PATTERN**

Although I wouldn't recommend this at all. This is a working example with the anti-pattern you requested.

Sibling1 has a `useEffect` which updates a state on the common parent `App` with its method `showData`. Whenever `showData` changes, the effect is run again and keeps it updated. `showData` is a memoized callback. You can add a depedency array to update this memoized callback whenever some other variable changes.

**Source:** [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

```js
function App() {

  const [sibling1Method,setSibling1Method] = React.useState({method: null});
  

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Sibling1
        setSibling1Method={setSibling1Method}
      />
      <Sibling2
        sibling1Method={sibling1Method}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Sibling1(props) {
  
  const showData = React.useCallback((formValue) => {
    console.log('A click from Sibling2 is triggering a Sibling1 Method');
  },[]);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    props.setSibling1Method({method: showData});
  },[showData]);
  
  return(
    <div>Sibling 1 </div>
  );
}

function Sibling2(props) {
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>Sibling 2 </span>
      <button onClick={()=>props.sibling1Method.method()}>Click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I believe that as you said the best way to do this is to change the hierarchy of my components, now i change Form to be a child of Table. Hope this will have a good impact. Thanks cbdev420 !!

Comment: Glad it helped. If you wish, you can accept and upvote my answer too. Happy coding to you.